# Installing SketchUp2017 with PlayOnLinux requires Win7 SP1 - How to install the Service Pack?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Some basic info:
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
PlayOnLinux Installed: 4.2.10-a~xenial~Noobslab.com
Wine version installed via PlayOnLinux - 1.85

The version of SketchUp I have currently installed will no longer be supported at the 3D Warehouse for SketchUp in Jan 1 next year so I need to install a newer version. The install log for SketchUp 2017 shows:

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 5.2.2 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft Windows', phase BuildList
Reading value 'CurrentVersion' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft  \Windows NT\CurrentVersion'
Read string value '5.2'
Setting value '5.2 {string}' for property 'OsCurrentVersion'
Reading value 'CurrentBuildNumber' of registry key 'HKLM\Software \Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion'
Read string value '3790'
Setting value '3790 {string}' for property 'OsCurrentBuildNumber'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft Windows':
Property: [OsCurrentBuildNumber] = 3790 {string}
Property: [OsCurrentVersion] = 5.2 {string}
Running checks for command  'SketchUpPrerequisites64\MinimumWindowsVersion'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property  'VersionNT' and value '6.1': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and     value '6.1': true
Result of checks for command 'SketchUpPrerequisites64\MinimumWindowsVersion' is 'Fail'
'Microsoft Windows' RunCheck result: Fail
A prerequisite failed for Package "Microsoft Windows"
Package failed with message "Installation of SketchUp requires Windows 7 Service Pack 1 or later."
```

The PlayOnLinux log shows:

```
[12/10/16 17:05:49] - Running wine-1.8.5 --version (Working directory :  /home/chris/.PlayOnLinux/shortcuts)
wine-1.8.5

PlayOnLinux logfile
-------------------
Date: 12/10/16 17:05:49

> PlayOnLinux Version
  4.2.10
> uname -a
  Linux localhost 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> lsb_release -a

> wine --version
  wine-1.8.5
> POL_WINEVERSION
  1.8.5
> WINEPREFIX
  /home/chris/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/SketchUp2017
> Distribution
 Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
> glxinfo \| grep rendering
  direct rendering: Yes
> glxinfo \| grep renderer
  GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
  GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Q45/Q43 
> OpenGL libs (Direct rendering testing)
  32bits direct rendering is enabled
  64bits direct rendering is enabled

[12/10/16 17:06:25] - Running wine-1.8.5 cmd /c echo %ProgramFiles%     (Working directory : /home/chris/.PlayOnLinux/shortcuts)
C:\Program Files (x86)
[12/10/16 17:06:58] - Running wine-1.8.5 /home/chris/Downloads /SketchUpMake-en-x64.exe (Working directory : /)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {5eec90ab-c022-44b2-a5dd-fd716a222a15},   0x401123, 0x42d1f0, 0x42d208
fixme:advapi:EventSetInformation 2, 0x42a538, 43
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated.  Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm wanting to use SketchUp to design some of the gardening projects I have using PVC pipe.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue, struggled to solve it, yet solution was already available on winehq, which I'd like to share for future visitors.

Following these steps precisely from winehq resolved the issue for me (other similar approaches led to same issue with Service Pack):

```
$ export WINEARCH=win64
$ winetricks vcrun2013 vcrun2015 corefonts
$ winetricks win7
- Download .NET Framework 4.5.2 (offline version) and install it with the command:
$ wine start /unix NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
- Then run the actual SketchUp installer:
$ wine SketchUpMake-it-x64.exe (or the Pro version, either works)
- Follow the installation steps
- Run SketchUp (you can run it just fine from the .desktop created by WINE itself)
```

My guess here is that `winetricks win7` was the actual solution, but honestly I'm not sure. It worked on my ubuntu 18 (using `docker-wine` environment from `scottyhardy` , wine v4.0) for SketchUp 2017. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, winetricks win7 is the solution. SP1 is automatically catered for if you select the right windows environment in wine. Alternatively, you can run winetricks > select default wine prefix > change settings > select windows 7 (or later).

Answer (score 1):

## A simple-ish way to install Sketchup Make 2017

---

### **1.  Install Wine if you don't already have it**

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install wine
```

### **2.  Make sure the wine folder/prefix is set to handle 64-bit programs**

export WINEARCH=win64

### **3.  Install winetricks**

```
sudo apt install winetricks
```

### **4.  Launch winetricks**

Click OK to bypass any warnings, then

**a)** Navigate to **Select the default wineprefix -> Install a Windows DLL    or component**. Check **riched20** and click OK.

**b)** Navigate to **Select the default wineprefix -> Install a Windows DLL or component**. Check **dotnet452** and click OK.

The last step installs Microsoft's .NET Framework. Winetricks will install dotnet40 first. It takes some time. Click OK multiple times to ignore all the warnings and accept the Microsoft license terms until the install has finished.

### **5.  Download a free version of Sketchup Make 2017**

https://www.sketchup.com/download/all

### **6.  Open winetricks again**

Navigate to **Select the default wineprefix -> Change settings**. Check **win7** and click OK.

### **7. In winetricks, select "Run explorer"**

Navigate to the location of the Sketchup installer. Double-click to install.

A launcher for Sketchup should be automatically created in your Ubuntu menu for future use.